# What is the Super Retina HD device pixel ratio?

Tags: ios

Apple just announced iPhone X which has Super Retina HD. I know Retina's  device pixel ratio is x2 but what is the Super Retina HD' device pixel ratio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's 3x (like it is on iPhone 7+). See [Designing for iPhone X](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/fall2017/801/) video.

The [Building Apps for iPhone X](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/fall2017/201/) also has good information.